# Are there way of moving ubuntu server?

Tags: server

Are there way of moving ubuntu server to another service provider?

Not just setup, install from scratch, I want to just clone server harddisk and restore it from another server (Amazon EC2).

Answer (score 0):

Directly cloning a disk probably won't work, since the different server providers have *very* different methods for managing virtual disks and allocations.

I'd recommend you take a look at backup and restore options, for example you could backup the full system from the original server then restore it to the new server you spun up on the new service provider.

I'd recommend `duplicity` for doing this, since it has a lot of good documentation and backends available. With a full system backup (i.e. include `/etc /var /opt /home` and whatever else,) it should result in a mostly identical restored system.